# Changing all the values inside a list into one with a singular value, different lengths

Tags: python

So I currently have a bunch of mocks list such as this one.
Sample:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['c','b','a','d']
l3 = ['c','a','b','d','x','z']
l4 = ['a','c','a','a']
```

What I want to do is check if any of the values inside each of these lists, is equal to 'a'. If so, I want to change each single object inside the list into 'a'. It's worth noting that the lists have different lengths. Also I want to change one by one inside a loop. Mostly because my physical issue is on a dataset. Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Given the above lists, I want to produce:

```
l = ['a','a','a','a']
l2 = ['a','a','a','a']
l3 = ['a','a','a','a','a','a']
l4 = ['a','a','a','a']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether any of the elements are equal to `'a'`, and then replace the elements of the list if such an element exists:

```py
for lst in [l, l2, l3, l4]:
    if 'a' in lst:
        lst[:] = ['a'] * len(lst)

print(l, l2, l3, l4, sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```py
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Comment: Well just out of curiosity, if instead of a it was a list of values. How would you do it?

Comment: What do you mean by a "list of values"? As in, instead of a string, one of the elements was a list containing some elements, and you wanted to check whether a list with those elements was one of the elements inside another list?

Comment: Yes exactly as you said it

Comment: If `target` is the list you want to match, then do `if target in lst`.

Comment: But then how would i know which element inside the target list got matched with the element inside the lst? I know this is outside of the question but would appreciate some help

Comment: I'm not sure why that would matter. You don't need to know which element was matched in order to perform this replacement process.